# Show only one error message inside try catch

Tags: java, sql, database, jframe, try-catch

Inside my Add button click i have typed some codes which works very well and inside my try catch block i have two JOptionPane messages. **1st message is to say that info has been added sucessfully and the other which is inside the catch block is to say that Client cannot be added twice to the same tour on same date.**

**When I run this code without any primary key violations it shows the 1st message (which is correct) but also shows the 2nd message as well. It should show only 1st message and stop.  But after showing both messages it adds to the database.**

**When I enter something that will give primary key violation, it shows add successfully message( which is wrong) and then the Error message. It doesnt add to the database.**

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code.

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

        if (txt_name.getText().isEmpty() || txt_escort.getText().isEmpty()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Cannot have empty fields");
        } else {

            clientID = combo_client.getSelectedItem().toString();
            tourID = combo_tour.getSelectedItem().toString();
            date = combo_date.getSelectedItem().toString();
            escortID = txt_escort.getText();
            clientName = txt_name.getText();

            try {

                query = "INSERT INTO tourRParticipant(ClientID,Name,TourID,StartDate,EscortID) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement stm = db.getconn().prepareStatement(query);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added successfully!");
                stm.setString(1, clientID);
                stm.setString(2, clientName);
                stm.setString(3, tourID);
                stm.setString(4, date);
                stm.setString(5, escortID);
                rs = stm.executeQuery();

                rs.next();

                conn.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR..Client cannot be added to the same tour with the same date");
            }

            ViewTable();
        }
    }
```

Comment: write this line JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added successfully!"); after rs = stm.executeQuery();

Comment: Since you're displaying the first Message before actually executing the jdbc query, chances are you're getting an `SQLException` which is still caught.

Comment: This is because you do not verify what Exception is thrown. Your description in your catch block is wrong.
Also, you don't verify that the Client is added before printing it is added successfully. Move that line till after the execution of the query

Comment: @SpringLearner I tried it before. But still it gives the same output.

Comment: @Dragondraikk now it doesnt display the successful message after pasting it under the excecution. It just shows the error even though I typed correctly

Comment: Well yes. That's because there is an error. Why would you want it to tell the user that it was successful when it was not? Instead you should see what the error is about and fix that problem. You should either log the error or use `e.printStackTrace()` to actually see what's going on.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you display the success message `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added successfully!");` before executing the update. It should be displayed after the insert statement is executed.

Second of all, you should call `executeUpdate` not `executeQuery`, since you are executing an INSERT statement.

```
stm.executeUpdate();
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added successfully!");
```

Comment: @ShanD You should print the details of the exception you catch (`System.out.println(e)` in the catch clause). This would help you understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Added successfully!");
```

should be after

```
rs = stm.executeQuery();
```

And as pointed in other answer, `stmt.executeUpdate()` should be used instead of `stmt.executeQuery()`. As you are passing an update query to `executeQuery()` method, it is throwing exception. That's why you are always getting two messages.

Comment: I tried that... now it doesnt even show Added Successfully message. It just shows the error even when I entered data correctly

Comment: That is because you are using `executeQuery` for updating. Correct method to be used while updating is `executeUpdate`.

Comment: Yeah I changed to executeUpdate() then it says int cannot be converted to ResultSet

Comment: That is because `executeUpdate` returns the number of rows updated which is an `int` and not a `ResultSet`. To understand working of these, go through this link: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)